# Disabling Author Page only for subscribers

Tags: functions, author

does anybody know, how to disable the author page only for subscribers ?

So it should be only disabled for the user role "subscriber"

Comment: Why isn't the more relevant question how to modify the "author link" and its elements when and where a subscriber's (screen-)name happens to appear? Are there other ways that author pages come into play (lists or menus, or custom profiles or some such), or that users might find them?

Comment: Because I dont want modify the author link. I only want, that for subscribers no author page is awaylabel

Comment: Wait - are you saying you don't want subscribers to be able to visit Author pages - aka front end profile pages? What about non-registered visitors? Or are you referring to the back end edit profile pages? The question still isn't making much sense to me, especially since now you're working on a function that does target the author link...

Comment: No, I dont want, that if somebody would call up the author page with the link of a subscriber, so that it would come out an author page of an subscriber, that this wouldnt be possible

Comment: well - I'm still not sure how anybody is getting in the position to call up the author page other than through the author link, and I'm not sure where it's appearing other than in comments - so either you modify author links generally, comment author links specifically, or change the behavior of author pages - or there's something else about your situation I'm not processing!

Comment: You got right, I know...bute I wanna do this only for security reasons...anyhow it shold be possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, perhaps, there is no `get_user_role` function, so not surprising that the earlier answer produced an error.

As per my discussion with Rodney Hawk, I still wonder about the point of this exercise - or what security function this operation serves that wouldn't be better served by other methods - but, if the preferred objective is to redirect everyone from the author profile page if the author is a "subscriber," then you might use something like the following:

```
//for authors template (author.php or variant)
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author')) ;

$author_roles = $curauth->roles ;

if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $author_roles ) ) {
    //probably would want something a little different, but good enough for example
    wp_redirect( 'http://redirect-here.com', 404 ) ;
    //always follow wp_redirect with exit...
    exit ;
}
```

Note: The $curauth code used above seems to come directly from the Codex. Given the specifics of this case (only for author.php template, only for subscribers), you might be able to write the first lines more simply as follows:

```
$author_roles = get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name') )->roles ;
```

Note 2: Haven't tested the redirection part.

Comment: Perfect ! Only the ,404 doesnt function on redirecten. Without it works perfectly. Many  thanks !

Comment: Good - please mark the answer as good! (Yeah, like I said, didn't check the redirect part except to add the "exit." How you handle the redirect... that's up to you, but if it's doing what you want, I'd say let good enough be good enough!)

Comment: Yes thank you again. I marked the answer as good !

Comment: Sure you did it right? Not coming up for some reason as "answered."

Answer (score 0):

I was trying in this way but it doesnt function:

```
function wpse74924_filter_the_author_posts_link( $link ) {
    // Since $author_id doesn't get passed to this filter,
    // we need to query it ourselves
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );

    if ( user_can( $author_id, 'administrator' ) ) {
        // This is an administrator
        __return_false();
    }
    // Otherwise, return $link unmodified
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_author_posts_link', 'wpse74924_filter_the_author_posts_link' );
```

Comment: Hi. It would help people answer if you moved this into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In author.php you could redirect visitors somewhere else if it's the author page for a subscriber.

```
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));

if ( get_user_role($curauth->ID) === 'subscriber' ):
    wp_redirect( 'http://redirect-here.com', 404 );
    endif;
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this...its happening nothing :( No redirection !

Comment: In this kind its function...I think the Problem ist the wp-redirect... <?php if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ):?>
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://theos.in/");
 
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
<?php endif;?>   How to give 404 to this ?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake, let me correct it.

Comment: Further your script only does function for the current logged in user. But I need the redirection, if the author page of an user that is only subscriber would be shown.

Comment: This should do it

Comment: No sorry...php error !

Comment: Cant find the mistake...only white site...php error !